# How can I change label Value by clicking in a picturebox in C#?

Tags: c#

[image]This is my first post in here and I m trying for 3-4 months now to learn c#.
As the title says I have this simple method in a Guy class:

```
public void UpdateLabels()
{
   MyLabel.Text = (Name + " has placed " + MyBet.Amount + "$ " + "on " );      
}
```

In image as you can see the label updates by giving value to numericUp button
but I want when I click a bear to get the name of the bear in label

Thank you a lot .

Comment: This is how I want to make it work int this picture: http://postimg.org/image/rh08b2fxn/

Comment: It was in front of my eyes .I was trying to treat the pictureboxes as texts which was wrong.I could see them but C# couldn't so I made texts that C# could see them and would apply to pictureboxes choices.Thank you all for your time and helping me out!

Comment: Not sure what that means.  Glad you figured it out....

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `Click` event handler to the `PictureBox` controls, like shown in the following compact Lambda-style notation sample:

```
img1.Click+=(s,e)=>{ UpdateLabels();}
```

where `img1` is a `PictureBox` control name of that one containing "Bear" image. The same technique you can apply to other `PictureBox` controls.

*Note*: you may need to modify the `UpdateLabels(s,e)` to extract sender `s` information (like: `PictureBox _px = s as PictureBox`)  and apply the updates to the corresponding `Label`, thus, the event subscription will look like:

```
img1.Click+=(s,e)=> UpdateLabels(s,e);
img2.Click+=(s,e)=> UpdateLabels(s,e);
.....
```

pointing to the same event handler (btw, in case of WPF I would recommend to use `TextBlock` instead of `Label` control; correspondingly it could be `Image` control instead of `PictureBox`).

Hope this may help.

Comment: Hi @Taw: Please see my extended answer: it's all been added already. Kind regards,

Comment: Yes, that's right: the solution can be used in both WinForm and WPF app. I have clarified this. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Double Click the PictureBoxes to get their `Click()` event.  From there you can set the Label to the correct value:

```
    public void UpdateLabels()
    {
       MyLabel.Text = (Name + " has placed " + MyBet.Amount + "$ " + "on " + label1.Text);      
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Brown Bear";
        UpdateLabels();
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Red Bear";
        UpdateLabels();
    }

    // ... etc ...
```

*Change `label1` to the name of your label (which I hope is better named).

Comment: I have the click event handler and I change the text I want but the thing is I can t change the label that has the UpdateLabels method.              private void redBear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            label4.Text = "Red Bear";
            label4.Location = new Point(470, 410);
            
        }.I want to add in the label the name of the bear after the word on as you see in picture.

Comment: You need to create and update the proper reference to the current Label do this in the RadioButtons'  CheckedChanges event(s)!

Comment: You could also call your `UpdateLabel()` method from there.  Change it so the label value is included...see updated answer.

Comment: I added a  string property which I was trying to give it values and then make this value same with the value in UpdateLabels ()  method which MyLabel.Text = (Name + " has placed " + MyBet.Amount + "$ " + "on " + myChoseNBear);//The myChosenBear is a string which I gave it values from main form by calling it through an instance but nothing happened.

Comment: "The myChosenBear is a string which I gave it values from main form by calling it through an instance but nothing happened."  Can you show how you're calling it "through an instance"?

Comment: Idle_mind I had a Guy chooseBear = new Guy(); instance created.Then i said chooseBear.myChosenBear = "brown bear" or I even created new string that  was string brownBear ="brown bear" and  chooseBear.myChosenBear = brownBear ;no errors but nothing happened.

Comment: Is `Guy` the Form (the one we see in the screenshot)?...or a Class just for holding data about the "Guy"?  If the former, I'm guessing you don't need a new instance, just use the current form via `this.myChosenBear`.

Comment: No Guy is a class that hold the method UpdateLabels and some other info about the guys names cash etc.The picture is in main form of winforms public partial class Form1 : Form and they all belong to main namespace .Thank you a lot for your time Idle_Mind again.

Comment: ?...wait....if `Guy` has `UpdateLabels()`, but the picture is of `Form1`, then how is `UpdateLabels()` accessing `MyLabel` which is on the Form?  Need a better picture of all the players involved here...

Comment: My best guess right now is that you should have an instance of `Guy` declared at **Class** level (in Form1) instead of inside the event handler.

Comment: @George DM what did you code in the  RadioButtons' CheckedChanges event(s)??? This is the key, really!

Comment: Here is the link of my terrible code.Don t mind the cooments which are in greek language.https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9v7rlbu010ca0lh/AABaHgd3QVnYV44GOOadBft_a?dl=0 or in here the rar http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07171018387960591416

Answer (score 0):

It was in front of my eyes .I was trying to treat the pictureboxes as texts which was wrong.I could see them but C# couldn't so I made texts that C# could see them and would apply to pictureboxes choices.Thank you all for your time and helping me out!